# Is there a Bitcoin gadget for Windows 7?

Tags: exchange-rate, windows

Is there a Bitcoin gadget for Windows 7, which features conversion rate with EUR? (i.e. EUR/BTC)

Comment: A gadget meaning for translation from your own site, or a site that provides conversion, like http://preev.com

Answer (score 3):

This is the one I'm using: http://www.domchi.cc/mybitcoins/

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the minimalist Obi-Wan live EUR/BTC ticker app, hosted there: http://dre.tx0.org/

While not technically a Windows 7 gadget, it essentially does exactly what you are looking for and I've been using for a couple months with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [MultiBit](http://multibit.org) (v0.3.3 at time of writing) has a ticker from the [XChange](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange) project. While it is not currently a widget, it does offer a range of currencies from MtGox (with Intersango and others to follow later). I suppose you could resize it to fit your purpose until the "widget mode" makes it into an upcoming milestone release.

Answer (score 0):

MyBitcoins gadget

You can download it here:
[MyBitcoins gadget](http://domchi.cc/mybitcoins/)

Answer (score -1):

You could embed the URL [MtGox] http://mtgoxlive.com/orders?currency=EUR (works for some other currencies too) into a Windows gadget but I know of no existing software.

Comment: Could you please link a gadget to embed urls, then?

Comment: I don't know of any. I was suggesting a possible course of action. Perhaps Windows has such a gadget included or available for download.